# How to handle Wi-Fi switch/connection lost on Mobile Device in Javascript

Tags: javascript, android, google-chrome, dns, xmlhttprequest

In my project I have call nearly 400 synchronously XHR requests in a row.

```
function executeRequest(url, data){
    var requestObj = new XMLHttpRequest();
    requestObj.open("POST", url, true);
    // prepare the request with some headers
    // set some eventHandler e.g. onerror, onreadystatechange, onabort

    requestObj.send(data);
}
```

So far so good. It's works fine in nearly 97% of the cases.

Some customers reported an error on android devices.

**POST < url > net::ERR_NAME_NOT_RESOLVED**

That what i found. This is an message from Chrome browser. That points to an DNS problem.

But this confusing me. The device can successfully send and received e.g. 245 requests and the 246 has now a problem with the DNS?

Its not any time the same requests that ends up with **net::ERR_NAME_NOT_RESOLVED**
Sometimes its the request 111 other times the request 358.

So i have a hard time to investigate this problem, because of reproducing this. Yesterday I found out that i can force this kind of error by continuously changing the WiFi connection.

I got 2 different **net::** errors

1. **net::ERR_NAME_NOT_RESOLVED**
2. **net::ERR_ADDRESS_UNREACHABLE**

Which one i got are depending on the state that my Mobile Device is.

On execution time from

```
requestObj.send(data);
```

1. If the device try to connect to the hotspot, than i got
   **net::ERR_NAME_NOT_RESOLVED**
2. If the device try to connect to the internet, but is connected to the hotspot, than i got **net::ERR_ADDRESS_UNREACHABLE**

My knowledge is not so good, how the DNS and Chrome works with it.

I try to handle this problem with an error callback.

I want to resend this request a second time.
Whats working for me right now is, that i wait a several time (30sec) and send this request again.

```
function executeRequest(url, data){
    var requestObj = new XMLHttpRequest();
    requestObj.open("POST", url, true);
    // prepare the request with some headers

    requestObj.onerror = function(e){
        setTimeout(function() {
            executeRequest(url, data);
        }, 30000);
    } 
    requestObj.send(data);
}
```

Is there is better way to handle this kind of error?
I don't like to wait 30 sec.

I'm also looking for some states that i can work within an callback.

Answer (score 0):

Use the retry pattern:

```html
 
Definitely not the way to go - while(!done); will go into a hard loop and take up all of your cpu.

Instead you could do something like this (untested and you may want to implement a back-off of some sort):

function tryUntilSuccess(options, callback) {
    var req = https.request(options, function(res) {
        var acc = "";
        res.on("data", function(msg) {
            acc += msg.toString("utf-8");
        });
        res.on("end", function() {
            var history = JSON.parse(acc);  //<== Protect this if you may not get JSON back
            if (history.success) {
                callback(null, history);
            } else {
                tryUntilSuccess(options, callback);
            }
        });
    });
    req.end();

    req.on('error', function(e) {
        // Decide what to do here
        // if error is recoverable
        //     tryUntilSuccess(options, callback);
        // else
        //     callback(e);
    });
}

// Use the standard callback pattern of err in first param, success in second
tryUntilSuccess(options, function(err, resp) {
    // Your code here...
});
```

Or just remove the timeout

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I have an retry mecanism. If i remove the timeout i run into the same net:: error we got before. Until the Wi-Fi connection is stable. What i was looking for is something like navigator.onLine.